# cant get document in firestore(React Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get document(s) value from firestore, but I'm getting an error with my query.

This is the path in Firebase:

```
/users/currentuser.uid/confirmed-appointments/10/10
```

This my useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //Later be used here
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("confirmed-appointments")
      .doc("10") //10 = october , 11 = november , 12 = december and etc....
      .get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
      })

  }, [])
```

I want to go through all the docs inside 10/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform a normal query on the subcollection using its full path:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .doc(uid)
  .collection("confirmed-appointments")
  .doc("10")
  .collection("10")
  .get().then(querySnapshot => {
    for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    }
  })
```